# Obtener coordenadas de mi ubicación

Tags: android-studio, geolocalización, gps

estoy haciendo una app con android studio, que obtiene las coordendas y las envia a una bd. 
Tengo una duda, si quiero obtener las coordenadas, el usuario si o si tiene que tener la ubicacion(gps) activada no? o con la red wifi o 3g de alguna manera se puede lograr esto?, o tiene que tener si o si datos y ademas el gps?
Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias formas diferentes de obtener las coordenadas del smarthphone
Serían:

-GPS

-Dirección IP

-Datos del sensor de tu dispositivo

-Información sobre elementos cercanos a tu dispositivo como, por ejemplo, puntos deacceso 
 Wi-Fi, antenas de servicio de telefonía móvil y dispositivos con el Bluetooth activado

Pero realmente para mi lo más optimo es el gps, por que ya lo he utilizado en otras aplicaciones y me ha dado buenos resultados.

Espero haber podido responder tu pregunta.

Comment: Ok, pero el gps si estas en un lugar cerrado, o un edificio por ejemplo, el gps no funciona, no seria mejor hacerlo siempre por ip? muchas gracias

Comment: No sé a que te refieres con que no funciona, el gps nunca deja de funcionar, independiente de que tengas o no internet, pero pues depende para que necesites las coordenadas